# Inner join in access only returns records that are whole numbers or .5 variations

Tags: mysql

I had an inner join between two tables that was working yesterday and this morning.  I added new data and now the inner join only returns records that are whole numbers or have a .5 decimal place attached, all other records with values XX.1, .2, .3, etc. do not show up.  Is there a solution for this issue?

Comment: what is your table structure and please provide your query whtat have you done

Comment: Can you provide some more data in the question?  Preferably the data type of the column, sample query, and expected output

Comment: The query is: 
INSERT INTO Media_Inspections ( InspectionID, Video_Location, Video_Name )
SELECT Inspections.InspectionID, Left([Mainline].[DVS_File],(InStrRev([Mainline].[DVS_File],"\"))) AS Expr1, Right([Mainline].[DVS_File],((Len([Mainline].[DVS_File]))-((InStrRev([Mainline].[DVS_File],"\"))))) AS Expr2
FROM Mainline INNER JOIN Inspections ON (Mainline.Date_ = Inspections.Date) AND (Mainline.Length_surveyed = Inspections.Length_Surveyed) AND (Mainline.Sewer_ID = Inspections.Pipe_Segment_Reference);

Comment: is this about MySQL?

Comment: Both fields are number fields, with decimal places of 1

Comment: But it is the actual join inner join that isn't working, not the query itself

Answer (score 0):

Both field size need to be long integer to pull all records from an inner join in this setting. In this case, one was double, creating the issue.